# Is there any reason mouselistener isn't responding?

Tags: java, mouselistener

Basically, I want to get the coordinates of the mouse when it is pressed. I've done it before and I know it's possible, but it doesn't seem to be working with my current jframe/jpanel set up and I cannot understand why.

Here's a summary of my mouselistener code:

```
package com.JJEngine.input;

import java.awt.MouseInfo;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;

import com.JJEngine.output.Window;

public class Mouse implements MouseListener {
    public Mouse(){
    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
        //This is where i'd do my stuff if this actually worked
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {

    }

}
```

and here's my jpanel/jframe
    package com.JJEngine.output;

```
import java.awt.Container;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import com.JJEngine.input.Mouse;
import com.JJEngine.main.Main;

import custom.GameMain;

public class Window extends JPanel{
    public static JFrame frame = new JFrame();  
    public static JPanel gamePanel = new JPanel();
    private Container window;


    public Window() {
        frame.addMouseListener(new Mouse());

        frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH); 
        frame.setUndecorated(!GameMain.BORDERS);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        // Custom options
        frame.setSize(Main.game.X, Main.game.Y);
        frame.setTitle(Main.game.NAME);
        frame.setResizable(Main.game.RESIZABLE);

        window = frame.getContentPane();
        frame.add(gamePanel);
        frame.add(Main.render);

           // Built options
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setFocusable(true);
            frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        }
    }
```

My guess is I will have to restructure my entire Window class. If that is the case, why? Thanks in advance.

Comment: your mouse listener code has nothing in it, no println's no nothing -- so what are you expecting it to do?

Comment: A `JFrame` has a `JRootPane` which has the `contentPane` which sits between it and the user. It' possible that the mouse events are been consumed by either of these two component

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels It doesn't here but if it did, nothing would change.

Comment: I have solved it! In my window class,I added a canvas class to the JFrame. I added the mouselistener to that canvas object and for some reason that worked.

Comment: *"and for some reason that worked"* - It works because there are no components above your component which would otherwise consume the mouse events - this is how the API works